# How to get browser's navigation background color?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to apply my div color accordingly with the browser's navigation background color.

```
+---------------------------------+
| get navigation background color |
+---------------------------------+
+---------------------------------+
| apply div color according to    |
| browsers navigation bgcolor     |
+---------------------------------+
```

[image]

So, is there any technique that I can get navigation background color for different browsers including ie,safari, firefox,chrome,etc.

Comment: You hav'nt access on that! & based on IE: he has no basic color, the bar is translucent/opaque, how as you like "catch" that?

Comment: for other browsers? for ie any color between them!

Comment: javascript does not have access to this. I don't even think this is accessible on a plugin/extension/addon level, though I haven't gone looking at that in a while

Comment: can someone explain me why this is getting downvoted?

Comment: You'd for sure have to go to the plugin level, which would be a big pain for being cross browser

Comment: @bto.rdz I was wondering the same thing.. seems a legit enough question, regardless of whether or not it's doable